# Multivariable regression with scipy curve_fit: always off by a systematic amount

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have been doing multivariable linear regression (equations of the form: y=b0+b1*x1+b2*x2+...+bnxn) in python. I could successfully solve the following function:

```
def MultipleRegressionFunc(X,B):
    y=B[0]
    for i in range(0,len(X)): y += X[i]*B[i+1]
    return y
```

I'll skip the details of that function for now. Suffices to say that using the `curve_fit` wrapper in `scipy` with this function has successfully allowed me to solve systems with many variables.

Now I've been wanting to consider possible interactions between variables, so I've modified the function as follows:

```
def MultipleRegressionFuncBIS(X,B):
    #Define terms of the equation
    #The first term is 1*b0 (intercept)
    terms=[1]
    #Adding terms for the "non-interaction" part of the equation
    for x in X: terms.append(x)
    #Adding terms for the 'interaction' part of the equations
    for x in list(combinations(X, 2)): terms.append(x[0]*x[1])
    #I'm proceeding in this way because I found that some operations on iterables are not well handled when curve_fit passes numpy arrays to the function
    #Setting a float object to hold the result of the calculation
    y = 0.0
    #Iterating through each term in the equation, and adding the value to y
    for i in range(0, len(terms)):  y += B[i]*terms[i]
    return y
```

I made a wrapper function for the above to be able to pass multiple linear coefficients to it via `curve_fit`.

```
def wrapper_func(X,*B):
    return MultipleRegressionFuncBIS(X,B)
```

Here's some mock input, generated by applying the following formula: `1+2*x1+3*x2+4*x3+5*x1*x2+6*x1*x3+7*x2*x3`

```
x1=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53]
x2=[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54]
x3=[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]
y=[91, 192, 329, 502, 711, 956, 1237, 1554, 1907, 2296, 2721, 3182, 3679, 4212, 4781, 5386, 6027, 6704, 7417, 8166, 8951, 9772, 10629, 11522, 12451, 13416, 14417, 15454, 16527, 17636, 18781, 19962, 21179, 22432, 23721, 25046, 26407, 27804, 29237, 30706, 32211, 33752, 35329, 36942, 38591, 40276, 41997, 43754, 45547, 47376, 49241, 51142, 53079]
```

Then I obtain the linear coefficients by calling the following:

```
linear_coeffs=list(curve_fit(wrapper_func,[x1,x2,x3],y,p0=[1.1,2.2,3.1,4.1,5.1,6.1,7.1],bounds=(0.0,10.0))[0])
print linear_coeffs
```

Notice that here the p0 estimates are manually set to values extremely close to the real values to rule out the possibility that `curve_fit` is having a hard time converging.

Yet, the output for this particular case deviates more than I would expect from the real values (expected: `[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0]`):

```
[1.1020684140370627, 2.1149407566785214, 2.9872182044259676, 3.9734017072175436, 5.0575156518729969, 5.9605293645760549, 6.9819549835509491]
```

Now, here's my problem. While the coefficients do not perfectly match the input model, that is a secondary concern. I do expect some error in real life examples, although that is puzzling in this noice-less mock example. My main problem is that the error is **systematic**. In the example above, using the coefficients estimated by `curve_fit` the residuals are systematically equal to `0.10206841`, for all values of `x1,x2,x3`. Other mock datasets produce different, but still systematic residuals.

Can you think of any explanation for this systematic error ?

I post here because I suspect it is a coding issue, rather than a statistical one. I'm very willing to move this question to Cross Validated if it turns out I made a stats error.

Many thanks !